# Completeness Score feature requests

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Please indicate which items need attention in some way for completeness.

I suspect that the "Last Five Years" and "Time Frame" scores are because I have 2008-Current on my latest job, however the -Current is one of the suggestions when filling it out.

My score went down for having MORE than 5 liked technologies.

Comment: can't repro the score going down for more than 5 liked technologies, but the other suggestions are good.  I think in your case the "Last Five Years" and "Time Frame" are because one of your jobs doesn't have an end date (just says "May 2006"), so there are no jobs that cover 2007.

Comment: I started with more than 5 and then went down to 5 and the score went up, so maybe it had to do with my having more than 5 when the scoring was created.
Changing the May 2006 one fixed the last five years but not the Time Frame score.

Answer (score 1):

The page now gives much more detailed information about which sections need to be fixed to get the full points.